# Documents for ASP.NET health notification

Tags: .net, asp.net

Win Server 2003
IIS 6.0
.NET 2.0

I've set in web.config to let the web service send out emails for any events. Like this:

```
  <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add ... />
    </providers>
    <rules>
      <add ... />
    </rules>
  </healthMonitoring>
```

Is there any documents for me to look up the meaning for event code/ event message/ event detail code/ etc...

I also want to know what kind of events are in what event categories, so I don't need to send "all events" all the time. Please help, thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks John. However, this is really helpful. However, it seems to be still no document for the meaning of event messages.

Like I am getting this email:

Event code: 1002
Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: Hosting environment is shutting down.
Event time: 1/29/2011 12:31:49 AM
Event time (UTC): 1/29/2011 8:31:49 AM
Event ID: d70ea175365b46e89dc35bc722b0b3f3 Event sequence: 290 Event occurrence: 1 Event detail code: 50002

I want to know how what does this mean, any other info that I can dig into for further information, and how to fix this. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: What part don't you understand? The hosting environment (IIS) is shutting down.

Comment: Yea, but why is it shutting down? I was expecting there's a msdn page talking about this specific event and providing information for further investigation to find out the cause of shutting down. For now, my web service gets this shutting down like once a day. I am not sure if it's a bug and needs to be fixed or what.

Comment: Also, how to know which category this specific event at, so I don't need to receive "All Events".

Answer (score 1):

See [ASP.NET Health Monitoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx)